# Where can I ask questions about gaming history?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Currently, I have many historical questions (which have short, definitive, objective answers) that I would like to ask about games, and gaming. While much of gaming history is not necessarily well known, a lot of that is changing. Questions like:

- Why does Mario have a mustache? (yes, there is a non subjective answer to this!)
- Why did the original zelda have such strange enemy names?
- Why did early consoles have so few buttons?
- Why was Japanese Mario 2 not released in the United States?
- Why did John Romero leave id?

The answers to these questions can be found, and answers can be backed up with evidence, citations etc. Since this information is historical (over 30 years old some of it) it is not hidden behind non-disclosures, as some might assume. However, there is no Stack Exchange that I know of that accepts these types of questions about games, while there is a an ever expanding study of gaming history.

Edit: Just so those skipping the comments know, no, I am not allowed to post these types of questions on "Gaming" - though I wish I could.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com)? They even have a [[gaming-history] tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming-history), and although it only has four questions and three are closed, the other is highly upvoted, and the closed ones are closed because "*Questions asking for help identifying a game, whether based on a description, or feature list, or any other set of criteria (i.e. "What was the first game to…") are off-topic.*"

So, as long as your question isn't "which game has _____?", you should be fine asking there.

Comment: My questions of that nature have been closed aggressively there.

Comment: @baordog You don't even have a Gaming account. How have you asked questions there?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/207511/whats-the-deal-with-the-weird-enemy-names-in-zelda -- that's me. Please excuse the petulant arguing with the mod.

Comment: @baordog Whoops, sorry, I completely missed your Gaming account since it was at the very bottom of your accounts list. In any case, if you're not getting an answer on Gaming, you're not going to get an answer anywhere else on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: This makes me sad :( - if I can ask obscure questions about Anime, origin of genres that kind of thing, I would think gaming would make it too. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

[Gaming SE](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) would be your best bet. Gaming history isn't something they ever created an official policy on. They have a [question on meta about it](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2694/how-do-we-feel-towards-specific-questions-about-the-history-of-a-certain-game-me) dated back to 2011, but it doesn't appear to have formed any sort of official stance on the subject.

That being said, your third question sounds incredibly unconstructive for a Stack Exchange site, and your fifth question would be blatantly off-topic for any site on our network. Someone's personal choice to leave a company is not something that any scope would cover.